# PHP Form - Drop Down List - How To Display The Selected Option in the Variable

Tags: php, forms, variables, drop-down-menu

I am relatively new to PHP. I am taking a class and working on a form. So please keep that (me being new and learning) in mind if you decide to help. 8-)

Here is the deal. I have a form. I am using a drop down for the states. I have created a variable to echo out after the form has been submitted. The challenge is that the variable does not print. I am not sure how to get this to work. What I think I need if for the 'value' to get assigned to the variable.

I did search for a solution via google but I do not think I am using the appropriate search terms to find what I am looking for. For this form we are not using a database yet.

```
<select>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="CA">California</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option id="state" name="state" value="DE">Delaware</option>
</select>
```

Now the variable is assigned here:

```
 $state=$_POST['state'];
```

And then I have the echo here:

```
  echo '<li>State: ' . $state . '</li>';
```

When it prints out it just prints the State:

Can anyone help me understand why this is not working and how I can resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your help. Please let me know if you need any more info from me.

Comment: A valid HTML document will only contain unique ids occurring only once.  You have MANY options with the `id` of `state`.  Beyond that, it is the `select` field that is read by the submission handler -- give the `select` tag a `name`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="state">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
```

Change please.

Comment: `id` should go on the `<select>` as well, as it should be unique within the document.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, only `<select>` bears the name attribute, not `<option>`, remove those from them all.

- `<select name = "state">` bears the name attribute.
- `<option value = "AL">` bears the value.

You also did not post the rest of your form, therefore it's unsure if that is correct.

Make sure it contains a POST method.

I.e.: `<form action = "whatever_action_is" method = "post">...</form>`, `<select>...</select>` belonging inside the form tags.

- *whatever_action_is*, that could be `action=""` as self or `action="handler.php"`, being another file or the same one you're using; that is unknown.

If you are running both your HTML and PHP inside the same file, use a conditional statement.

I.e.:

```
if(isset($_POST['state'])){
   $state=$_POST['state'];
}

else{
   echo "Not set.";
}
```

- Otherwise, you may receive undefined index notices.
- `id="state"` ID's are unique, therefore you either need to give them different ID's, or use a class if you are using this with CSS. `class="state"`

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

HTML stickler.

`<li></li>` requires the `<ul></ul>` unordered list tags or `<ol></ol>` etc.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Depending on which type you want to use.